# Quick way to add new Bazel github external repository if you're lazy?

Tags: go, bazel

I'm using Bazel and gazelle to manage my Go project's BUILD.bazel files.

I'd like to be consistent across languages and avoid Go's specific vendoring tool.

I disabled vendoring for gazelle. It generates the BUILD entries wonderfully for those repositories, but I'm stuck with writing the WORKSPACE incantations for `git_repository` or `http_archive` myself. This of course can get tedious if a project I'm using has a lot of external dependencies.

Is there a more convenient way to do it? Could gazelle support updating the WORKSPACE file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: it looks like the Bazel team wants do add support for this to [Gazelle](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/389) but until that's done we could use the wtool:

```
$ go get -u github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/go/tools/wtool
$ github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio

This will update the WORKSPACE file accordingly. The command doesn't even have to be run from the repository root - which is nice.
```

Here's my the diff for my WORKSPACE after running the command above:

```
$ git diff WORKSPACE 
diff --git a/WORKSPACE b/WORKSPACE
index 3b15779..c170b60 100644
--- a/WORKSPACE
+++ b/WORKSPACE
@@ -50,3 +50,8 @@ go_repository(
     importpath = "google.golang.org/api",
 )

+go_repository(
+    name = "com_github_gordonklaus_portaudio",
+    commit = "e66c30a9c4ca11f93538cf8c004831bfb76f3838",
+    importpath = "github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio",
+)
```